# Where do I find the site column's XML file?

Tags: 2013, site-column

I want to view an XML definition of a site column. At the moment the only way I know of doing it is through a PowerShell script:

```
Get-SPWeb.Fields['MyField'].SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens
```

Is it possible to do the same through the UI or a SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ever since v1 of SharePoint Team Services, Microsoft has used `OWSSVR.DLL` to remotely invoke functions against SharePoint. It is part of  SharePoint Foundation Remote Procedure Call (RPC) protocol.

To read more about the `OWSSVR.DLL` command follow [URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478653.aspx) from Microsoft Blog.

The query:

```
https://fabifam.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={ListGuid}
```

allows to export a List Schema

### Usage

1. To determine List Guid, go to `List` - `List Settings` - copy List
   parameter from Url
2. Construct the following query:

   ```
   https://fabifam.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={ListGuid}
   ```

   where `{ListGuid}` corresponds to the List Guid
3. The list schema will be generated as demonstrated below:

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/). It is a free tool.

Comment: Thank you! Can it connect to remote SharePoint server?

Comment: No it does not allow connecting to remote servers. There is another similar tool which can connect to remote servers https://sprm.codeplex.com/ but this is only available for SharePoint 2010 not 2013

Comment: Cool. Thank you! What an unfortunate name though 'sprm'...

Answer (score 0):

You will find most of the out of the box columns and content types on the file system of your local server:

For Site Columns look at:

- **SharePoint 2010:**   HIVE14\Templates\Features\fields\fieldwss*.xml
- **SharePoint 2013:**   HIVE15\Templates\Features\fields\fieldwss*.xml

For Site Content Types take a look:

- **SharePoint 2010**    HIVE14\Templates\Features\ctypes\
- **SharePoint 2013**    HIVE15\Templates\Features\ctypes\

What is not in the xml files stored in the directories is other content types then the one that exist in the SharePoint Foundation. Additional content types come with additional features and can be found the features folder there.

For custom columns you will only find this using SharePoint Manager.

**Remember you can take a look into those files but you are note allowed to change this files. Handle with care.**